# Jquery stop function when user hovers over a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery ajax function:

```
function posts()
{
 pfunc = $.ajax({
         url: 'backend/posts.php',
         success: function(data) {
            $('#posts').html(data);
            $('#posts').fadeIn(2000);
            setTimeout(posts,2000);
        }
        });
}
posts();
```

And I want to stop the function when a user hovers over the div 'Posts' and resume when the user stops hovering over that div. Is there any way I could do that.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Once you invoke a function in the server, it will continue to run even though you've aborted the client-side calling function (ajax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function posts()
{
 pfunc = $.ajax({
         url: 'backend/posts.php',
         success: function(data) {
            $('#posts').html(data);
            $('#posts').fadeIn(2000);
            timer = setTimeout(posts,2000);

        }
        });
}
posts();
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#posts').hover(function(){clearTimeout(timer);}, function(){setTimeout(posts,2000);});
});
</script>
<div id = 'posts'></div>
```

Basically I added a mouser-over and mouse-out event handlers to the #post div which will clear and reset the timeouts respectively..

Answer (score 0):

you probably wnat to stop ajax function from running what you are looking for is called

```
    var pfunc = $.ajax({
             url: 'backend/posts.php',
             success: function(data) {
                $('#posts').html(data);
                $('#posts').fadeIn(2000);
                setTimeout(posts,2000);
            }
        });
```

more on hover event

```
$("idofyourdiv").hover(
  function () {
   pfunc.abort();
  },
  function () {
    pfunc();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd structure your base code somewhat like this:

```
var timer = null;
var request = null;

function posts() {
 request = $.ajax({
   url: 'backend/posts.php',
   success: function(data) {
     $('#posts').html(data).fadeIn(2000);
     timer = setTimeout(posts, 2000);
   }
 });
}

posts();
```

Next, to clear the timer, run `clearTimeout()` on the `timer` object. `timer` stores the id of your timeout function, which might not exist when you try to clear it, so safely clear it like this:

```
if (timer !== null) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Finally, you should abort the AJAX request, so just add that in as well:

```
if ((timer !== null) && (request !== null)) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  request.abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will check if your div is being hovered. And if it is true, the ajax call will be cancelled.

Trying not to modify too much your code:

```
function posts()
{
 pfunc = $.ajax({
         url: 'backend/posts.php',
         beforeSend: function(){
             if($("#posts").is(":hover")){
                return false;
             }
         },
         success: function(data) {
            $('#posts').html(data);
            $('#posts').fadeIn(2000);
            setTimeout(posts,2000);
        }
        });
}
posts();
```

Comment: Sorry. Should be $("#posts") instead of $("#oosts");

Answer (score 0):

javascript is not multi threaded so you can not stop a piece of code from running. As stated in other answers you may call abort on your ajax request but that is not stopping any code, it just aborting a request. And I'm not even sure its smart to abort the request when your just going to make the request again when the user stops hovering. I would let the request go thru and check the hover state in the response. If the hover state does not match your condition buffer the response and wait till the user stops hovering then resume your execution. Something like the following...

```
var hovering = false;
var onResponse = null;

$('.Posts').mouseover(function() {
    hovering = true;
});

$('.Posts').mouseout(function() {
    hovering = false;
    onResponse && onResponse();
});

function posts() {
 pfunc = $.ajax({
         url: 'backend/posts.php',
         success: function(data) {
                        onResponse = function() {
                            if(hovering) return;
                            $('#posts').html(data);
                            $('#posts').fadeIn(2000);
                            setTimeout(posts, 2000);
                            onResponse = null;
                        };
                        onResponse();
        }
        });
}

posts();
```